# Cannot read property "totalPrice" of undefined

Tags: angular

I have this code on my Angular 2 template.

```
<td class="hidden-xs text-center"><strong>Total: &#8369; {{carts.totalPrice}}</strong></td>
```

When I log `carts.totalPrice` in console, it shows the correct value. Here is the object value.

[image]

What I suspect here is that the template loads faster than the object that's why it tells me that it cannot read the property. Am I right?

EDIT: This is my method on getting the carts value.

```
getItems(){
    this._cartService.getCartItems(localStorage.getItem('currentUserId'))
        .subscribe((cart) => {
            this.cartItems = cart.products;
            // this.totalPrice = cart.totalPrice;
            this.carts = cart;
            console.log(this.carts)
        },
        (err) => console.log(err));
}
```

Error stack trace.

[image]

Comment: Show how you defined carts property in Component?

Comment: done! I edited my question

Comment: if you can log it in the console then it's not undefined

Comment: i've edited to show the error stack trace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<td *ngIf="carts" class="hidden-xs text-center"><strong>Total: &#8369; {{carts.totalPrice}}</strong></td>
```

Comment: this is what I am looking for! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

lennys answer is completely correct, I thought that I would present a couple more options.

Since the retrieval of data is asynchronous, it usually means that the view is rendered before data has arrived, just as you suspected. This then means that at the point when the view is rendered your object is still `undefined`/ `null`.

You would have a few options to solve this.

- Initialize your Object
- Use the [**safe navigation operator**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator)
- Use `*ngIf`

---

Depending on the case, it can help that you simply **initialize your object** in your component, so that it will not be undefined:

```
carts: Object = {};
```

---

**Use the safe navigation operator (`?`).**

```
{{carts?.totalPrice}}
```

This is a convenient way to guard against null and undefined values in property paths. The view still renders but the property path is displayed as blank.

---

**Use `*ngIf`** (check lennys answer)

The main difference with `*ngIf` and the safe navigation operator is, that the part from the template which is wrapped inside the element with `*ngIf`, will be completely removed from the DOM, until there will be values in `carts`.