# bind the json value in ngmodel in angular 2

Tags: javascript, java, json, angular, typescript

This is my json response. How can bind the rewards.rewardName value in `[(ngModel)]` in angular 2.

```
 [
  {
   "id": 18,
   "gname": "learning ramayanam",
   "goalCategory": "Education",
   "goalSubCategory": "short-term",
   "goalDesc": "good",
   "rowStatusCode": "D",
   "createID": "1",
   "createTS": null,
   "updateID": "Ram",
   "updateTS": null,
   "rewards": {
     "rewardID": 1,
     "rewardName": "Laptop"
   }
 ]
```

This is my code buddy how can i bind the value in ngModel

```
   ngOnInit() {
   this.route.params
        .forEach(params => {
            this.isEdition = !!params['id'];
            if (this.isEdition) {
               // this.getDocument(params['id']);
   this.itemPromise = this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/dy/get-goal?id=' 
    + 
   params['id'])
   .map(res => res.json()).toPromise();

   this.itemPromise.then((item: any) =>  {
   console.log(item);
   var arr = JSON.parse(item);
   this.item = arr[0];
   return item;
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you take a look at the [**official http tutorial**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html). I would suggest you use either promises or observables. Seems you would like to use promises, so I'll set up that example for you. Also please consider using a service (like in the tutorial), that is recommended, but here I'll use your existing code:

```ts
// remove "this.itemPromise = " and just have the code below
this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/dy/get-goal?id=' + params['id'])
   .toPromise()
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(data => {
      this.item = data[0];
   })
```

When this is done, there will be an `undefined` issue since this is asynchronous. Check this one: [Cannot read property "totalPrice" of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558821/cannot-read-property-totalprice-of-undefined)
Two-way-binding, i.e `[(ngModel)]` doesn't support the safe navigation operator, so you'd want to split this to one-way-binding and `ngModelChange`:

```html
<input [ngModel]="item?.rewards?.rewardName" 
    (ngModelChange)="item?.rewards?.rewardName ? item.rewards.rewardName=$event : null" >
```

Props to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36016472/6294072

Here's a [**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/hHaNC3GYLtNANL0ha0uf?p=preview) using service, which I suggest you do ;)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Parse your json to an object.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

Then bind it to your element

```
[(ngModel)]="obj.rewards.rewardName"
```

Comment: i got this error buddy what can i do                                                                                                   
  ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'rewardName' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'rewardName' of undefined
    at Object.View_RewardseditComponent_0.co [as updateDirectives] (ng:///AppModule/RewardseditComponent.ngfactory.js:1152:37)

Comment: Missed that obj will be an array here.
try:

`var arr = JSON.parse(json);
 var obj = arr[0];`

To get the first element.

Comment: i got this error dude                                                                                 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: ngOnInit() {
   this.route.params
            .forEach(params => {
                this.isEdition = !!params['id'];
                if (this.isEdition) {
                   // this.getDocument(params['id']);
    this.itemPromise = this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/dy/get-goal?id=' + params['id'])
      .map(res => res.json()).toPromise();

    this.itemPromise.then((item: any) =>  {
      console.log(item);
      var arr = JSON.parse(item);
      this.item = arr[0];
      return item;
    });

Comment: You are already parsing the json by doing 
`map(res => res.json()` if "this.item" is the object you are binding to remove `var arr = JSON.parse(item);` and try `this.item = item[0];`